# How to send erc20 token with web3 without smart contract abi?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20

I created a token in the Ropsten network.  It wants abi.json when transferring with Web3. But the token I created did not give it.

My token etherscan link https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe4bcb47da515d78a05de9f0861808fa97284129c

Verification failed. I want to make a transfer with node js web3 without verification. How can I do that?

Comment: It seems an ERC-20 token, if that's the case you do not need it to be verified to use. With the standard ABI you can use https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/how-to-transfer-erc20-tokens-using-web3js to send transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it done quickly, I wrote a small interface for interacting with smart contracts that don't provide any abi and just general testing. It's hosted at https://lovingthewired.github.io/

All you would have to do is, fill in the details under "Send Transaction":

1. fill in the "to" field with the contract address `0xe4bcb47da515d78a05de9f0861808fa97284129c`
2. Enter the function signature `transfer(address,uint256)` in the function field
3. Enter the function parameters: `{receiving address 0x..},{amount}`

[image: Example]

Metamask will recognize the transfer function and you will be able to send the transaction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method without the abi file you can do it by encoding the signature.

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/5829347e537473b6de2d9fda2c830f2be6f47968/docs/web3-eth-abi.rst#encodefunctionsignature

Once you've encoded it you can sign the transaction and submit it manually.