# How to send a specific token from a wallet when there are multiple tokens

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have two ERC20 tokens in my Metamask wallet, say TOKEN_1 and TOKEN_2.
How do I send TOKEN_1 programmatically to another wallet?

Comment: Hey Doug! Great question, especially since this is a common use case. Can you check out this answer and see if it solves your problem? 

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/how-to-transfer-erc20-tokens-using-web3js

Answer (score 0):

For each token, there is a transfer function that allows you to transfer the token from one account to another. I use brownie, and this is what it would look like.

if the contract was maybe transferring some DAI to another address.

```
tx = dai.transfer(addressOfReceiver,amountInWei,{"from":yourAccount})
tx.wait(1)
```

You can check the link below if you know a bit about brownie.
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-contracts.html

But otherwise, for each token, there is a transfer function that allows you to transfer a token from one account to another.